# Nutrient turning into bacteria according to the Slow Growth Law instead of the 2nd Law

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, complex-systems

I'm reading a paper by Charles H. Bennett on different metrics for complexity in the physical world: http://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/94_Bennett.pdf

In a paragraph on page 35, where he describes thermodynamic potentials
as putative metric for complexity, the following statement is made:

> The growth of bacteria following inocculation is a thermodynamically
>   irreversible process [...]. [It] is accompanied by a
>   decrease in free energy, and [...] is vastly
>   more probable than its reverse: [...] the spontaneous transformation of
>   bacteria into high-free-energy nutrients.

and

> The unliklihood of a bottle of sterile nutrient transforming itself
>   into bacteria is therefore not a manifestation of the second law, but
>   rather of a putative new "slow growth law" which forbids complexity,
>   however it is defined, to increase quickly, but allows it to increase
>   slowly, e.g. over geological time in biogenesis.

To me, this doesn't add up. How is it more probable for bacteria to emerge than the reverse? The "spontaneous transformation of bacteria into [...] nutrients" is what I usually would expect if the bacteria died, isn't it?

And for the second statement: It seems like he's making the point, that it is *still* not likely for nutrients turning into bacteria, *even though* it would be thermodynamically favoured. Am I understanding this correctly? Going from high free energy to low free energy is entropically favoured so should be more probable and the reason why it is still improbably is because of this shady slow growth law?

Comment: To be fair, bacteria are nutrients even before they die. Regardless, I believe his basis of argument is flawed. There's no real limit to how quickly a system's complexity can be increased, as long as there's energy entering the system at a high enough rate to work the change.

Comment: Can you give an example of a system that acquires complexity quickly? Because it seems true that at least some systems not evolve quickly, exemplified by bacteria in evolutionary time scales.